# How to merge random changes in VS TFS as a whole in one go?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfvc

I need to go for merging using 'Selected change sets' as I only want to merge my changes and not other developers'.

But I could not select all my changes for merging as they are random and seems merging can be done in bulk only if my changesets are consecutive.

Any way to handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** merge multiple changesets in one go, unless the changesets are in sequence. Take a look at below similar question:

- [how to merge two changesets only (TFS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905901/how-to-merge-two-changesets-only-tfs)
- [TFS merge changeset into file with pending change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623999/tfs-merge-changeset-into-file-with-pending-change)

There had bee a related uservoice: **[TFS to merge multiple, non-continuous changesets.](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/2638075-tfs-to-merge-multiple-non-continuous-changesets)** However got declined by TFS PM.

> Thanks for the feedback on this idea. We have reviewed this feedback
> and determined that we will **not be able to** complete this
> suggestion in the foreseeable future.
>
> *Matt Mitrik TFS Program Manager*

You have to merge either a single changeset or a sequential changesets in one go.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what you mean by 'in one go', as you can open the Merge dialog multiple times selecting one or more (continuous) changeset(s) and when done, committing them as one changeset.

This leaves you with one changeset with all your merged changesets.

**Do note**, that when merging non-continuously there are of cause problems if your changes 'need' changes that are not merged.